# How to get the latest data based on date time field in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fetch the latest data of every date time field in sql. Can anyone help me to solve this please..
This is my table structure.

```
| ID | USER   |       TIME          |
-------------------------------------
|  2 |    abc | 2009-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  3 |    abc | 2009-01-01 22:00:00 | 
|  5 |    abc | 2009-01-01 10:00:00 | 
|  6 |    xyz | 2009-01-02 01:00:00 |
|  7 |    xyz | 2009-01-02 22:00:00 | 
|  8 |    xyz | 2009-01-02 10:00:00 |
```

And i want the output like this.

```
| ID | USER   |       TIME          |
-------------------------------------
|  3 |    abc | 2009-01-01 22:00:00 | 
|  7 |    xyz | 2009-01-02 22:00:00 |
```

Edit: Change in requirement. As I told, I want every users latest record for each date.

```
| ID | USER   |       TIME          |
-------------------------------------
|  2 |    abc | 2009-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  3 |    abc | 2009-01-01 22:00:00 | 
|  5 |    abc | 2009-01-01 10:00:00 | 
|  6 |    xyz | 2009-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  7 |    xyz | 2009-01-01 22:00:00 | 
|  8 |    xyz | 2009-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 10 |    abc | 2009-01-04 09:00:00 |
| 11 |    abc | 2009-01-04 02:00:00 |
| 15 |    xyz | 2009-01-04 04:00:00 |
| 25 |    xyz | 2009-01-04 06:00:00 |
```

And i want the output like this.

```
| ID | USER   |       TIME          |
-------------------------------------
|  3 |    abc | 2009-01-01 22:00:00 | 
|  7 |    xyz | 2009-01-01 22:00:00 | 
| 10 |    abc | 2009-01-04 09:00:00 |
| 25 |    xyz | 2009-01-04 06:00:00 |
```

Comment: clear your requirements first and post what you have tried so far.. we are not here to do code for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

> SELECT ID,USER,TIME FROM tbl_name Group By User Order By TIME DESC, USER ASC;

Comment: run query in http://sqlfiddle.com and see your. its due to wrong ans. we need date with max time as in question **latest data of every date**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY name ORDER BY name asc, time DESC LIMIT 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1057/15)

Comment: But it will return the data order by Time desc, I want only one single data of every user which is the latest one in table

Comment: then you need add where condition for each date or manage it through php code.

Comment: why downvoted?? i give at least near by answer. now it can be handled from code side..

Comment: @JaydeepPandya i give at least near by answer. now it can be handled from code side.

Comment: @bluto no we need to fetch latest record for each not by customer. so both are diff and can't manage from code side using this query.